# Emmet shortcut key suggestion in VS code on linux mint

Tags: html, linux, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, emmet

I need advice on how to write emmet HTML shortcut key in VS code on Linux mint for below. Thanks in advance.

```
   <div><span>span=1</span></div>
  <br>
  <div><span>span=2</span></div>
  <br>
  <div><span>span=3</span></div>
  <br>
  <div><span>span=4</span></div>
  <br>
  <div><span>span=5</span></div>
  <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to create an 'emmet' command, but you could create an html snippet to accomplish the same thing.  Click on `Preferences->User Snippets->html` and it should open a file called html.json in the editor.

You can add the following to that html.json file:

```
"emmet spans": {
        "prefix": "e-span",
        "body": [
            "<div><span>span=1</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=2</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=3</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=4</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=5</span></div>",
            "<br>"
        ],
        "description": "5 spans with line breaks"
    }
```

A working sample snippet file would look like:

```
{
    // Place your snippets for html here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and 
    // description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. Placeholders with the 
    // same ids are connected.
    // Example:
    // "Print to console": {
    //  "prefix": "log",
    //  "body": [
    //      "console.log('$1');",
    //      "$2"
    //  ],
    //  "description": "Log output to console"
    // }
    "emmet spans": {
        "prefix": "e-span",
        "body": [
            "<div><span>span=1</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=2</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=3</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=4</span></div>",
            "<br>",
            "<div><span>span=5</span></div>",
            "<br>"
        ],
        "description": "5 spans with line breaks"
    }
}
```

Once that file is saved you should be able to edit .html files and when you type `e-span` that html snippet will be added to your .html file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still I am looking for emmet shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0):

Emmet shotcut below will give the result you expected. You can find more on [emmet cheat sheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

```
((div>span{span=$})^br)*5


<div><span>span=1</span></div>
<br>
<div><span>span=2</span></div>
<br>
<div><span>span=3</span></div>
<br>
<div><span>span=4</span></div>
<br>
<div><span>span=5</span></div>
<br>
```